# Jmeter-selenim driver javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:No such property: org for class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have below code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.*
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import openqa.selenium.OutputType.*;

// 1. Go to a page with a form
WDS.browser.get('http://mobile.yellow.com.au')
// 2. Enter characters into the text input field

WDS.browser.findElement(By.id('clue'))sendKeys('tyres')
```

And i am getting below error

> javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException:
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class:
> Script32 at
> org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158)
> at
> java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:262)
> at
> com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:99)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)

Could some one please help

#jmeter #performance

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with your code, it runs just fine.

You can remove unnecessary [imports](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) and even get rid of them totally by putting [fully qualified reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html)

```
// 1. Go to a page with a form
WDS.browser.get('http://mobile.yellow.com.au')
// 2. Enter characters into the text input field

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('clue'))sendKeys('tyres')
```

If you still experience problems:

1. [Reinstall JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) from scratch
2. Add WebDriver Sampler **only** using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. Restart JMeter to pick the plugin up

Comment: I have used java script earlier as below

'wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.name('loginfmt')));'

Could you please suggest how to do in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and in the end it boiled down to (hidden)  `ClassNotFoundException`. In our case it was apache-commons lang3 which was missing. In your case it could be `org.openqa.selenium`. Make sure the libs are available on your classpath.